# Using a tabbar (like iPhone) or a submenu for Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, uitabbar

I'm developing an App in iPhone and a version for Android.

The iPhone version of the App uses a Tabbar on the bottom of the screen (for other screens / ViewControllers: Home, Favorites, Search in a list, ...).

I want to make the layout of the 2 versions of the App (the one for iPhone and the one for Android) the same as much as possible according to the best layout guidelines.

Android App's usually uses not a tabbar, but it's with a SubMenu. But, I find more an more Android App's that uses a tabbar at the bottom of the screen in stead of a submenu for handling this. I know that a TabBar on the bottom of the screen is not usual for an Android App and may seem strange for those users.

**So, what I want to know is may it be OK to use a tabbar like iPhone at the bottom of the screen, or is it NOT DONE for Android?** (Also according to screen use optimalisation and the android UI patern guidelines : by this I mean uses the mast of the screen for the App itself and not for navigating through the App).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent Android pattern for the 'Tabbar' is 'ActionBar', you can find more information on this widely-used pattern here: [Android Patterns - ActionBar](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/action-bar)